# Launchctl does not load service on boot

Tags: macos, launchd

I installed **mysql** via **homebrew** in osX 10.10. It comes with plist file located in `/usr/local/opt/mysql/homebrew.mxcl.mysql.plist`. The contents:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
  <key>KeepAlive</key>
  <true/>
  <key>Label</key>
  <string>homebrew.mxcl.mysql</string>
  <key>ProgramArguments</key>
  <array>
    <string>/usr/local/opt/mysql/bin/mysqld_safe</string>
    <string>--bind-address=127.0.0.1</string>
    <string>--datadir=/usr/local/var/mysql</string>
  </array>
  <key>RunAtLoad</key>
  <true/>
  <key>WorkingDirectory</key>
  <string>/usr/local/var</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

I created a symlink, added permissions and stuff and said launchctl to load it and save.

```
sudo chown root:wheel /Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.mysql.plist
sudo chmod 644 /Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.mysql.plist
sudo launchctl load -w /Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.mysql.plist
```

But after reboot it doesn't load mysql as well as it doesn't save the entry. I can clearly see this using `sudo launchctl list | grep mysql`

How can I get the item to remain in launchd subsequent reboots?

Comment: When you say "at boot" do you mean before any user logs in or when the user that loaded the plist logs in?

Comment: @bmike I mean if I reboot computer there is not trace of my service in launchctl